# ¿Cómo realizar correctamente esta consulta en SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, subconsultas

Estoy en proceso de pasar algunas consultas de mi trabajo de Access a SQL server. La consulta con la que tengo problemas es la siguiente:

```
SELECT dbo_coev.coev_num_ope, Last(dbo_coev.coev_des_eve) AS ÚltimoDecoev_des_eve, Max(dbo_coev.coev_fec_ini) AS MáxDecoev_fec_ini
FROM dbo_coev
GROUP BY dbo_coev.coev_num_ope
HAVING ((Not (Last(dbo_coev.coev_des_eve)) Is Null));
```

Mi problema es que no soy capaz de obtener el ultimo registro de coev_des_eve. Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
SELECT (coev_num_ope), max(coev_des_eve) AS ÚltimoDecoev_des_eve, max(coev_fec_ini) AS MáxDecoev_fec_ini
 
FROM (
  SELECT
    coev_num_ope,
    (coev_fec_ini),
    coev_des_eve,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY coev_num_ope ORDER BY (coev_fec_ini) desc) AS rn
  FROM
    vive_segu.dbo.coev
) m 
WHERE rn = 1 and (coev_des_eve) is not null
GROUP BY coev_num_ope;
```

Que me trae los últimos registros de operación por fecha, pero no el ultimo de coev_des_eve, como muestro en las siguientes imagen:

[image: En Access]

[image: En sql]

Cualquier ayuda seria de gran utilidad.

Comment: No entiendo el critero que utilizas para decir que el registro `88770` es el último (el que está resaltado con azul). ¿Podríás explicar cual es el criterio que utilizas? (¿el último ordenando como?). Sería util que a partir de esos datos de ejemplo muestres cual sería la salida esperada de la query que buscás.

Comment: te recomiendo que uses esta herramienta: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ada23/3/0 solo borra el contenido de los 2 textbox y puedes armar tu propio ejemplo de base de datos y consulta... ayuda tambien a darte una buena respuesta.

Comment: coev_num_ope posee valores repetidos, por lo que tengo que filtrarlo siguiendo el modelo de Access, ahora mismo me está devolviendo la operación basada en la última fecha (tercera columna), pero además necesito que me entregue el ultimo registro de la segunda columna, en Access se usa last, la cual no existe en sql server.

Comment: Cuando dices "el ultimo registro de la segunda columna" ¿ordenando como? Al hablar de último, hay una referencia implicita a un orden.

Comment: Acces hace una aberracion semantica del SQL, ya que Last trae algo que no existe en SQL, y es el ultimo valor leido de ese campo al hacer el group by... algo que no existe en ninguna otra base de datos. Ahora, deberias definir cual es el valor que queres traer.. si es el mismo valor que pertenece al max, max no te va a servir, y vas a necesitar joinear con la misma tabla para buscar ese valor....

Comment: Claro, ese es mi principal problema, access hace cosas que no puedo hacer en sql directamente, por lo que tengo que estar buscando como reemplazar sus funciones cada 5 minutos, pero con este last me superó, lo peor es que esta es solo una subquery de muchas otras, que también están llenas de funciones como LAST y IIF.

Comment: TIenes que tener muy claro que información queres que te traiga la query. Si no entendemos el problema es imposible resolverlo. Lo mas facil es presentar un conjunto de datos de ejemplo, y a partir de ellos cual sería el resultado esperado.